# Favourited questions credit

Tags: support, badges

Do users who ask questions that are favourited a lot (by other users) get any sort of credit e.g. badge etc or is this just a convenience for those reading the question?

Comment: You can find the full list of badges here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/badges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two badges for having your question favorited. You get a [silver "Favorite Question" badge](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/favorite-question) if 25 people favorite your question and a [gold "Stellar Question" badge](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/stellar-question) if 100 people favorite your question. Both badges can be awarded multiple times.